# need help in htaccess redirect for 3000 pages

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

need help as we have a joomla site, 1.5 yrs old now when we were doing seo audit, surpirisngly found over 3000 pages having url as undefined in it

ex-1 
incorrect url :

`www.example.com/undefined/index.php?option=com_usedcar&view=search&Itemid=3`

correct url -

`www.example.com/index.php?option=com_usedcar&view=search&Itemid=3`

ex-2 incorrect url :

`www.example.com/undefined/index.php?option=com_forms&view=pages&layout=shop&Itemid=2`

correct url -

`www.example.com/index.php?option=com_forms&view=pages&layout=shop&Itemid=2`

the term **'undefined'** is just screwing up as leading to all duplicate content
is there any way to do 301 redirect for pages with undefined to without undefined and rest of the url remains same

thanks, in anticipation

**Update**

Update, i've tried using this code but still not able to achieve desired result

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/undefined.*$
  RewriteRule .*  /     [L,R=301,DPI]
```

by using the above code in htaccess the Original url -

```
  http://www.xxx.com/undefined/index.php?option=com_easyblog&view=entry&id=42&Itemid=91
```

is changed to new url -

```
   http://www.xxx.com/?option=com_easyblog&view=entry&id=42&Itemid=91
```

If you see, though undefined is removed but the new url is missing index.php from the actual correct url, can anyone help on this .. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried hit n trial
seems its solved by replacing * with index.php